# Construindo select em HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistência, hql

Estou começando a usar JPA com hibernate e estou com duvidas sobre as query HQL, pesquisei um pouco sobre as Query hql só que não consegui entender muita coisa.
Quero fazer esse select em hql só que não entendi como transforma-lo em hql

```
select idUsuario FROM usuarios where login = 'user'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suponha uma classe mapeada e anotada com JPA/Hibernate que represente `Usuario` com esses campos, refletindo uma tabela que você já tenha no banco de dados:

```
@Entity
class Usuario {

  @Id
  private long id;
  private String login;
  (...)

  //getters e setters

}
```

Agora suponha o seu método de consulta no banco que deseja trazer um `Usuario` a partir de uma propriedade `login`:

```
public Usuario getUsuario(String login) {

  //Pegando a sessao (pressupõe que você já tenha o factory de sessão configurado etc.
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

  Query query = session.createQuery("from Usuario user where user.login= :login");
  query.setString("login", login);
  Usuario usuario = (Usuario) query.uniqueResult(); //retorna um Object, por isso o cast obrigatório

}
```

A parte importante relativamente à sua dúvida está aqui. Definimos um nome qualquer para a variável que representa nossa classe (aqui, `user`) e definimos a propriedade dessa classe sobre a qual nós queremos basear nossa consulta (`login`, mas poderia ser nome, idade, profissao etc.), acessando o objeto como fazemos normalmente em Java (objeto.propriedade, ou seja, `user.login`):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Usuario user where user.login= :infoDeLogin");
```

//Aqui você faz a ligação do parâmetro usado na query com o parâmetro usado no método.

```
query.setString("infoDeLogin", login);
```

Veja que a query começa com `"from Usuario"` e não com um `"select *"`, que normalmente seria o esperado. Isso porque, quando você quer trazer toda a entidade, esse início é desnecessário, bastando começar com o `"from"`, como feito aí.

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, eu tinha pesquisado como fazer isso, só que não tinha conseguido entender que depois do `FROM` viria a entidade criada, pelos exemplos que tinha lido achei que fosse algo relacionado com a tabela `FROM nome_tabela` agora ficou bem de boa com essa sua explicação. Super obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, o seu pensamento é correto. "Por trás dos panos", o framework, ao criar a query SQL converte a entidade na tabela para a qual o objeto `Usuario` está mapeado. A diferença é que, no HQL, você usa os objetos e propriedades Java em vez das tabelas e campos do banco.